# how to manually craft tx data in golang WITHOUT ethclient

Tags: go-ethereum, golang

how do i manually craft tx data (the actual DATA field in a tx) in golang without ethclient? i am trying to craft tx data to be signed later. lets assume i am trying to call a solidity function like `myFunc(bool, address, address, address[], uint)`

all of the ethclient examples require connecting to some rpc with ethclient.Dial() which i cannot do.

thanks so much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The data for the transaction sent to the contract consists of the signature of the function being called (4 bytes = 8 hex characters) followed by a list of parameters packed according to the rules set out here -https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/113394/how-output-of-abi-encode-calculated

The signature of a function is defined as the first 4 bytes (8 hex characters) of the sha3-hash of its declaration string, in your example - "myFunc(bool,address,address,address[],uint)". Spaces and tabs should be removed from the declaration. In your case, the signature of the function will be **f6fe3edf**.

Answer (score 0):

True, you can't send transactions to a node without connection to it. and in `golang` you should use `ethclient.Dial()` to connect to a `JSON-RPC` server.
If you don't have a node to connect use [Infura](https://infura.io/) to get a free url to a node.